# FireDAC MSAcc ODBC Driver broken after KB4484218 update

Tags: delphi, ms-access, firedac

My solution uses a ms-access database and FireDAC's 'MSAcc' Driver to access the database (*.mdb).

Some of my customers are facing issues since installing a january windows update for Office ([KB4484218](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484218/january-7-2020-update-for-office-2016-kb4484218) - note that depending on the version of office that's installed on the computer, the same patch could be applied with another KB. For referencing purposes i'll list them below).

The application that used to work on this same computer now no longer boots and fails when establishing the db connection.
I've rolled back this specific KB and the application is working again.
I'm aware of at least one other software vendor affected by this issue.

My questions are the following :

- Is anybody else affected by this?
- Does anybody know if this is FireDAC-related or a wider issue?
- Has anyone been able to find information from Embarcadero or Microsoft on this?

Updates that might trigger this issue to my knowledge :

*Office 2010: Description of the security update for Office 2010 (KB4484127)*

*Office 2013: Description of the security update for Office 2013 (KB4484119)*

*Office 2016: Description of the security update for Office 2016 (KB4484113)*

*Office 2016 (KB4484218) 32-Bit-Edition*

*Office 2016 (KB4464586) 32-Bit-Edition*

*Office 2016 (KB4484168) 32-Bit-Edition*

**UPDATE :** 
As requested, here is a bit more context and info on this issue.

```pascal
  FDConnection1.Params.DriverID := 'MSAcc';
  FDConnection1.Params.Database := Edit1.Text; //path to .mdb file
  FDConnection1.Open;
  FDQuery1.Connection := FDConnection1;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add( 'SELECT * FROM ' + edit3.Text); //insert column name
  FDQuery1.open;
  FDQuery1.first;
  ShowMessage(FDQuery1.FieldByName(edit2.Text).AsInteger.ToString);
  FDConnection1.Close
```

Executing the code above on a system that doesn't have the KB4484218 installed, everything works properly and the application show the value.
Executing the same code on the same machine after applying KB4484218 however, I get a Access Violation on 'ACECORE.DLL'

[image: Access violation]

This is consistent with Microsoft's release note for KB4484218 indicating that this specific DLL has been modified.

My bet is that MS did modify this component of the MS Access driver. Thus breaking at least FireDAC's implementation of it.

Comment: You need to make your q clearer.  You use the word "boots" when I think you mean "starts".  But even if you make that change, then it seems incorrect because if your app won't start, it won't get as far as attempting to open the connection to the db, so how can you know that that fails.

Comment: Can you describe the issues with Firedac's MSAcc driver more precisely? Until today I can't see any issue but we use here Office 2019 which might not be affected.

Comment: "fails when establishing the db connection" could benefit from showing any error messages or describing how it fails.

Comment: @SchneiderInfosystemsLtd Please see my message above, i added the "UPDATE" section.

Comment: @Brian Just updated my post above.

Comment: @MartynA Just updated my post above.

Comment: In this situation, it is best to write a bug report at https://quality.embarcadero.com.

Comment: You could also check if the ODBC driver is still working properly by using another DB wrapper than Firedac, e.g. by connecting the DB via ADO. If this is still working the Firedac is the root cause of this issue. Otherwise the ODBC driver is propably not longer stable

Comment: For anyone reading this, an issue has been created here :https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27471
No answers so far.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had exactly the same problem, and I solved it, like this:

1. Put the `FDPhysMSAccessDriverLink` component on the form.
2. Set the `ODBCDriver` property to `Microsoft Access Driver (* .mdb)`

That solved the problem, because then ODBC uses an old DLL that Microsoft did not mess up.

Comment: This worked and solved the problem.when using FireDAC and the KB4484218.

Comment: Right. This works if you're still in the development phase. If like me, your application is already deployed to hundreds of customer's site, this is no longer an option.